# Unexpected behaviour while executing my Custom Maximum Likelihood code. It jumps to uncalled functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, machine-learning, regression

I am currently writing a Machine Learning library in Python. The first class, Linear Regression, went without a hitch. However, the second class, Maximum Likelihood Regression, is playing tricks on me. Let me show you the class:

```
class MaximumLikelihoodGuassian:
    """
    Calculate the maximum likelihood of the regression.
    """
    __X = []
    __y = []
    __trend = []
    __mean = 0
    __variance = 0

    def __init__(self, X, y):
        """
        The class constructor.
        :param X: The first train dimension.
        :param y: The second train dimension.
        """
        self.__X = X
        self.__y = y

    def __calculate_mean(self):
        """
        Calculate the mean of the Gaussian distribution.
        :return:
        """
        ret = []
        for xs in self.__X:
            ret.append((self.__trend[0] - self.__trend[1]) * xs)
        return sum(ret) / len(ret)

    def __make_X_matrix(self):
        """
        Add a column of all 1s to X.
        :return: The new matrix.
        """
        size = len(self.__X)
        ret = [[], []]
        ret[1] = self.__X
        for i in range(size):
            ret[0].append(1)
        return ret

    def __calculate_XTXInverse(self):
        """
        Calculate Xt, multiply it by X (in matrix form), then inverse it.
        :return: (XTX) Inverse.
        """
        tool_box = Math.ToolBox()
        x_mat = self.__make_X_matrix()
        x_t = tool_box.matrix_transpose(x_mat)
        x_t_x = tool_box.matrix_multiplication(x_t, x_mat)
        return tool_box.matrix_inverse(x_t_x)

    def __calculate_XTy(self):
        """
        Calculates matrix of X transposed multiplied by y.
        :return: XTy.
        """
        x_mat = self.__make_X_matrix()
        tool_box = Math.ToolBox()
        x_t = tool_box.matrix_transpose(x_mat)
        x_t_y = tool_box.matrix_vector_multiplication(x_t, self.__y)
        return x_t_y

    def calculate_trend(self):
        """
        Calculates the trend (XTX Inverse * XTy).
        :return: The trend.
        """
        x_t_x_inverse = self.__calculate_XTXInverse()
         x_t_y = self.__calculate_XTy()
        tool_box = Math.ToolBox()
        return tool_box.matrix_multiplication(x_t_x_inverse, x_t_y)
```

And here's the ToolBox class it often refers to:

```
class ToolBox:
    """
    Some utilities.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def matrix_multiplication(self, a, b):
        """
        Matrix multiplication.
        :param a: Matrix A.
        :param b: Matrix B.
        :return: The product of the two matrices.
        """
        return [[sum(a*b for a, b in zip(X_row, Y_col)) for Y_col in zip(*b)] for X_row in a]

    def matrix_transpose(self, a):
        """
        Transposes the matrix.
        :param a: Matrix to transpose.
        :return: Transposed matrix.
        """
        return [[a[j][i] for j in range(len(a))] for i in range(len(a[0]))]

    def matrix_inverse(self, a):
        """
        Inverse of the matrix.
        :param a: The given matrix.
        :return: The matrix inversed.
        """
        return [(1/a[i][j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))]

    def matrix_vector_multiplication(self, matrix, vector):
        """
        Multiply vector by matrix.
        :param matrix: The matrix.
        :param vector: The vector.
        :return: The product of matrix and vector.
        """
        if len(matrix) == len(vector):
            for i in range(len(matrix)):
                results = []
                items = 0
                for j in range(len(vector)):
                    items += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
                    results.append(items)
            return results
```

And I am calling the `calculate_trend()` function like so:

```
list_X = [1, 4, 6, 2, 1, 10]
list_y = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 44]

reg = Regression.MaximumLikelihoodGuassian(list_X, list_y)

 print(reg.calculate_trend())

Here's the problem. While it generates the following error:
  File "D:\SterriaLearn\Math.py", line 176, in matrix_vector_multiplication
    items += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But it shouldn't. I have debugged the code *carefully*, and it, in fact, does not throw an exception... THE FIRST TIME. It executes the `matrix_vector_multiplication()` function TWICE. However that I have only called it ONCE. I can't fathom why it happens. What I can't understand is that it jumps to `Playground.py`, the file in which I am calling the `calculate_trend()` from, when it shouldn't. Here's an accompanying video showing the debugging process (it's only 10mb):
partlyshaderly[dot]com[slash]debug.flv

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant to your issue or not, but it sure looks sketchy that all instances of `MaximumLikelyhoodGuassian` appear to be sharing the same `__trend` list.

Comment: @Blckknght Each class has its own training set. So it must have its own trend set. You can't fit multiple training sets with one class, only one. Counter-intuitive? You tell me. To me it's expected from OOP. I'm not sure I'm still fairly a beginner.